# Elixir Logger : metadata according to level

Tags: logging, elixir

In order to keep the log file clean and readable, I would like to print metadata according to their level...

e.g. : for debug / warn / error I would like to print metadatas like :file and :line

However for info, I really don't have the need for those informations...
Does it possible to print the metadata according to their level ?

It seems that it should be possible according to the way the metadata has to be added in the format: `$metadata[$level]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not possible through configuration (`$metadata[$level]` means that the [`Logger.Formatter`](https://hexdocs.pm/logger/Logger.Formatter.html) will spit out the metadata followed by level in square brackets.)

Luckily enough, [`Logger.metadata/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/logger/Logger.html#metadata/1) allows to fully configure your metadata.

Also, [`Logger.info/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/logger/Logger.html#info/2) accepts a metadata as a second parameter, so you might introduce your own macro to wrap `Logger.info` providing any metadata you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can implement [your own logger format](https://hexdocs.pm/logger/Logger.html#module-custom-formatting).

```
defmodule MyConsoleLogger do
  def format(level, message, timestamp, metadata) do
    # Custom formatting logic...
  rescue
    _ -> "could not format: #{inspect {level, message, metadata}}"
  end
end
```

It can satisfy your requirements by judging `level` and `metadata`. You can also find line and file in `metadata`, which has below fields.

> :application - the current application
>
> :module - the current module
>
> :function - the current function
>
> :file - the current file
>
> :line - the current line
>
> :pid - the current process ID